# Can comments really be older than the post?

Tags: support, comments, timestamps

I saw an answer that had comments that were older than the answer. How is this possible? Is it a bug, a feature or something else?

[image]

Comment: It's probably a result of a merge.

Comment: Do you have a link? Multiple time-travelling comments may be more difficult to account for. An "answer" can be converted to a comment (by moderators) (don't know if the conversion can be targetted as an answer). If that answer was earlier, you get the time-travel. Answers merged with other questions (an example discussed on meta this week) can appear prescient as well.

Comment: Although you've accepted the duplicate, please reconsider. There is absolutely no way that an answer made four minutes previously could be involved in a merge. Something else happened here, The offset in timings on your screenshot no longer exists, and is otherwise currently unexplained.

Comment: With @martijn's update, perhaps some more re-open votes, or a different duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for comments to be older than the post they are on.

For questions, comments are moved over when another question is merged into it, together with the answers from the other post. If an older question is merged into a newer, the comments will be older.

For answers, this could happen if another answer was converted to a comment. This is far less likely to happen; that an older answer was converted to a comment on a newer answer, but the possibility exists.

However, in your screenshot you merely left the page open for a while after loading the latest answer changes; the comments were all created after the answer was posted. *Relative* timestamps in a page are periodically updated, but when you click on the 'this post was edited' banner that updating stops; leave the page open for a while and the comment timestamps keep updating (to reflect how long the page was open). Simply reload the page if this bothers you.